# Safari fails XMLHttpRequest (POST) with ' Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers'

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari

I'm just trying to use httpbin to test out XMLHttpRequests.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var xhrToCheck = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhrToCheck.open("POST", "http://httpbin.org/post");
        xhrToCheck.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(this);
            }
        };
        xhrToCheck.send("post test");

    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What works:

1. The same POST request in Firefox and Chrome
2. GET requests in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari to the url http://httpbin.org/get and https://httpbin.org/get

The error I'm getting:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (post, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://httpbin.org/post. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (index.html, line 0)
```

Any help on why this issue is happening would be appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry, I guess my primary question is 1) How do I fix this issue so that POST requests on safari don't throw an error

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, some browsers check that the "host" and the "access-control-allow-origin" are the same or the access-control-allow-origin allows the host url to make that request, that way your browser protects you from [XSS](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in chrome you can disable that security feature ([here explains how](https://superuser.com/questions/384871/overriding-access-control-allow-origin-restriction-in-google-chrome)).

And there is even a [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) for that.